# Python - return value from dict if cell contains substring

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, substring, lookup

I'm working with excel file where one column contains "Description" (=strings i.e. "abc_123") and I need to create categories based on the description. I checked Fuzzywuzzy lib, but it doesn't quite suit my needs since the description can be quite long and category can be described by one word therefore mismatch rate is quite high.

How I did it in excel (case sensitive):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$50,MATCH(1,--NOT(NOT(FIND($A$2:$A$50,B2))),0)),"N/A")
```

The thing is in python my solutions return only exact matches and I'd like to return even partial matches (case insensitive if possible).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'a', 1: "b", 2: "abc"}, 'col2': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan}})
di = {"a": "1", "b":"2"}

    col1    col2
0   a   NaN
1   b   NaN
2   abc NaN

df.loc[df.col1.isin(di), 'col2'] = df['col1'].map(di)

col1    col2
0   a   1
1   b   2
2   abc NaN
```

I'd like col2:2 to be populated with "1", since it's the first match (a).

edit:
dictionary - dict{"Hosp":"Hospital", "emerg":"Hospital", "Fire":"Fire Department"}

I'd like:

"Hospital emergency" to return "Hospital"

"Hospi_emrgncy." to return "Hospital"

"Hopsital emergency" to return "Hospital"

"Fire in Detroit" to return "Fire Department"

Comment: Im'm sorry, but your question is unclear. Can you provide more sample data and the expected output?

Comment: This sounds like a job for machine learning. Prepare a dataset of examples, feed it to a classification algorithm and then let it try to classify your remaining data.
A good starting point would be to look at scikit learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for key, value in category_name.items():
    mask = np.column_stack([df['Description'].str.contains(key, na=False) for col in df])
    df2 = df.loc[mask.any(axis=1)]
    df2["Category"] = df2["Category"].fillna(value)
    df3 = df3.combine_first(df2)
```

Finally found the solution. By no means perfect, but this does the job if I have good enough dictionary.